# Loop over specific key words in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For a current project, I am planning to filter specific lines from a large data set. As I have several key words, I would like to perform the filtering process through loops, which are exemplified below with the two string combinations "Board Cultural Diversity" and "SOx Emissions To Revenues USD in millions".

The script below is however currently only returning values for the first loop ("Board Cultural Diversity"). The loop over the second words correctly sets up a file that however remains empty in terms of content.

Does anyone know where the error in thought lies?

```
import pandas as pd
import csv


df = pd.read_csv("constituents.csv")
df = df.fillna("")

file = ["Board Cultural Diversity", "SOx Emissions To Revenues USD in millions"]

for i in file:

    df = df[df['Area'] == i]

    df.to_csv(i + 'Constituents.csv')
    print(df)
```

Comment: Nailed it - many thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `df = df[df['Area'] == i]` overwrites the dataframe, `df`, just use `df[df['Area'] == i].to_csv(i + 'Constituents.csv')` or don't assign the filtered data back to `df`.

```
for i in file:

    # df = df[df['Area'] == i]  # this overwrites df
    df2 = df[df['Area'] == i]  # replacement

    df2.to_csv(i + 'Constituents.csv')
    print(df2)
```

Comment: Thanks Trenton - I will accept your answer as soon as the technical min. time has passed.

Comment: @M.S. Thanks, happy programming.